# How does WPF Binding navigate relationships?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, binding, master-detail

I'm trying to implement a master-detail relationship in the following way:

```
(shown in a ComboBox)                       (shown in a DataGrid)
|-----------|                               |------------|
| Customers |                               | Orders     |
|-----------|                               |------------|
| Id        |--- CustomersOrdersRelation ---| CustomerId |
| Name      |                               | OrderId    |
| ...       |                               | ...        |
|-----------|                               |------------|
```

But I also have an <All Customers> item in the combobox, for which I need to see all orders from all customers displayed in the details datagrid.

Here's a snippet of the XAML code:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="CustomersComboBox" ...>
    <ComboBox.ItemsSource>
        <CompositeCollection>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="{StaticResource nullCustomer}" /> <!-- I wrote my own class NullCustomer -->
            <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource CustomersCollectionViewSource}}" />
        </CompositeCollection>
    </ComboBox.ItemsSource>
</ComboBox>

<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=CustomersComboBox, Path=SelectedItem.CustomersOrdersRelation}" ...>
```

Now I've got two questions:

1. How does the Binding in the datagrid find `Path=SelectedItem.CustomersOrdersRelation` when combobox's `SelectedItem` (which is a DataRowView at runtime) doesn't have a property `CustomersOrdersRelation`?
2. What is the simplest way for me to modify my own `NullCustomer` class so that when I select <All Customers> I'll have the results of `AllOrdersCollectionViewSource` displayed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `DataRowView` implements [`ICustomTypeDescriptor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.icustomtypedescriptor.aspx), which probably is used by the binding system to determine how to get that property.
2. Also give it a property `CustomersOrdersRelation` which returns a `CompositeCollection` containing `CollectionContainers` for all the orders of the customers.

Comment: Thank you @H.B. I implemented the solution based on your answers and it works great now.